# Import XML to Dynamodb

Tags: amazon-web-services, etl, amazon-data-pipeline

I have a set of very large XML files and I would like to import them to dynamodb after doing some data massaging.

Is this possible through AWS Data Pipeline or some other tool? Currently this is done manually through a program that runs the ETL process.

Comment: The term "very large" is relative, how big are we talking (total size, number of records)?  Are you wanting to take records from the XML and insert them as items in DynamoDB or actually store the XML in DynamoDB?

Comment: Let me rephrase. The individual xml files are rather small (a few mb). But there is like thousands of them that need to be loaded. And I m looking to map the XML records to DDB records (do some basic transformation and load to DDB as records there)

Comment: The maximum record size for items in DynamoDB is 400 KB so I assume each item you are inserting are below that limit.  It sounds like the amount of data you have is in the range of a few GB.  It may be easiest to write a script/app in your favorite programming language and run the load off of your laptop if it is a one time process.  There may be no need to over-architect a solution when the brute force approach works just fine.

Comment: Trust me - This is not the ideal solution. I have done this now but I m looking to optimise this solution

Comment: I'm still trying to understand your requirements.  Are you wanting to optimize because this is an ongoing process?  Does it need to load data in faster?  There are lots of powerful tools you can use, but without understanding why you do not like your current "brute force" approach it is difficult to make a recommendation.

Comment: I m trying to process all the files and then start the process again. So I load the files in a directory, transform them, load them to dynamodb, load the updated versions of those files and start over (this goes on for ever).

I would like to leverage tools built for this sort of thing rather than building my own (as I have currently done). I would also like some management / reporting around this (what run and when, where it failed etc).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how much would the DataPipeline would help you get the custom processing of XML would help.

I would like to recommend few approaches [definitely non exhaustive options] - either way, it would be beneficial if you keep those XML files in S3.

1. Try Elastic Map Reduce Route [ Bonus Points for SPOT instances ]
2. Try using Amazon Lambda to process and push it to dynamodb
3. Try ElasticBeanstalk Batch Process

Comment: Could you elaborate please on how Lambda can help me load XML records? Do you mean place those files in S3 and write the transformation in node / java? I would also like some help understanding how EMR could work with XML files if you have done it before.

Answer (score 0):

Currently through Datapipeline it is not possible to directly import the XML into DynamoDB.

But if you preprocess the XML files and convert XML data to the format described in DynamoDBExportDataFormat http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-object-dynamodbexportdataformat.html, then you should be able to use the templates provided in the DataPipline console to accomplish the task http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBPipeline.Templates.html.